# Counting parameters in a neural network

Tags: neural-networks

Is there a feature to automatically count parameters in a model? In Keras one can use `layer.count_params()` to get a count of parameters in a layer or `model.summary()` to get a detailed summary of parameters and layer sizes for the whole net.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I could see I included all layers that have learnable parameters the correct way; if you spot any issues please feel free to leave a comment or correct my answer.

**layers with learnable parameters**

```
countparameters[
l_ConvolutionLayer | l_LinearLayer | l_ConstantArrayLayer | 
l_EmbeddingLayer | l_BatchNormalizationLayer | 
l_BasicRecurrentLayer | l_GatedRecurrentLayer | 
l_LongShortTermMemoryLayer] := 
<|NetExtract[l, "Type"] ->
(NetExtract[NetInitialize@l, "Arrays"] //Query[Select[ArrayQ]] //Map[Length@*Flatten])|>

countparameters[l_SpatialTransformationLayer] := 
<|NetExtract[l, "Type"] -> <|"Parameters" -> 6|>|>
```

**`NetChain` and `NetGraph`**

```
countparameters[l_NetChain | l_NetGraph] := l // Normal // Map[countparameters]
```

**other layers**

```
countparameters[_] := Nothing
```

---

**Example:**

```
lenet = NetChain[{
ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2],
FlattenLayer[], 500, Ramp, 10, SoftmaxLayer[]},
"Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}],
"Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]
]

lenet // countparameters
```

> ```
> {<|"Convolution" -> <|"Weights" -> 500, "Biases" -> 20|>|>, 
>  <|"Convolution" -> <|"Weights" -> 25000, "Biases" -> 50|>|>, 
>  <|"Linear" -> <|"Weights" -> 400000, "Biases" -> 500|>|>, 
>  <|"Linear" -> <|"Weights" -> 5000, "Biases" -> 10|>|>}
> ```

---

**Prototype for a fancy version for use with `NetGraph`**

Take a modular net build with `NetGraph` such as

```
module[n_] := 
NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[n, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2]}]

lenet = NetGraph[
<|
"conv_1" -> module[20],
"conv_2" -> module[50], 
"flatten" -> FlattenLayer[],
"dense" -> NetChain[{LinearLayer[500], Ramp, LinearLayer[10], SoftmaxLayer[]}]
|>, 
{"conv_1" -> "conv_2" -> "flatten" -> "dense"}, 
"Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}], 
"Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]]
```

then something like

```
summary[net_NetGraph] := Module[{sum, parameterCounts},
sum[x_Integer] := x;
sum[x : <|(_ -> _Integer) ..|>] := Total@Values@x;
sum[x_List] := x // Total;
sum[_] := 0;

parameterCounts = net // countparameters;

<|"Total" -> (parameterCounts // Map[sum, #, {0, Infinity}] &) , 
"Details" -> (parameterCounts // Map[sum, #, {1, Infinity}] &) |>
]
```

gives a nice overview how the learnable parameters are distributed throughout the network architecture.

```
lenet // summary
```

> ```
> <|
>  "Total" -> 431080, 
>  "Details" ->
>  <|"conv_1" -> 520, "conv_2" -> 25050, "flatten" -> 0, "dense" -> 405510|>
> |>
> ```

Comment: I think in the spirit of your question it is better to have `GroupBy[#, First@*Keys -> Values, Total]&` at the end of `countparameters[l_NetChain | l_NetGraph] ` . I.e. to have a definition like this: `GroupBy[l // Normal // Map[countparameters], (First@*Keys) -> 
  Values, Total]` .

Comment: @AntonAntonov See the edit at the end of my post.

Comment: I added correct handling of layers with setting `"Biases" -> None`